# In Magento 2.3.4, Maximum Sales Quantity validation is not working based on cart items

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I have simple products with custom options, where I can add the products with different options on cart. In cart page, its show different cart items.

**For Example:** Simple product with cutom options (color and size)

```
Cart Item 1: Black with small size
Cart Item 2: Green with small size
```

I added cart item 1 with maximum quantity. While adding the cart item 2 with maximum quantity it throws an error message as

**`The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart`**

**Excepted results**: It should add the item without throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed in the latest magento version 2.3.4 they updated the condition of maximum value from the cart per product in **CheckQuoteItemQtyPlugin** file.

Go to the file path:

```
vendor / magento/ module-inventory-sales / Plugin / StockState / CheckQuoteItemQtyPlugin.php
```

Here you can below code under **aroundCheckQuoteItemQty** function

```
$qty = max($this->getNumber($itemQty), $this->getNumber($qtyToCheck));
```

Override the plugin file and change the above code to

```
$qty = $this->getNumber($itemQty);
```